# Redirecting QObject::dumpObjectInfo()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is it possible to get the output of QObject::dumpObjectInfo() and display it through something other than the qDebug channel?  Ideally, I would like to get the output of this method into a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is impossible due to `qDebug()` calls are hardcoded in the method: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#line3689

But you can redirect debug channel itself by installing message handler: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler

Comment: Did you mean to say it is not "possible"?